# CGI bash/html : how to fill a list box with bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I need to develop a CGI in bash/html. I want to create a list box which would be filled automaticaly in using a text file.

I try this :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Content-type: text/html"
echo ""

echo "
<html>
<head>
        <title> CLUSTER GRAPH </title>
        <h1> Cluster Graph </h1>
<hr size="4" color="blue" >

</head>
<body>

<PRE>"

declare -A array

array=$(cat CLUSTER_1.txt | awk -F',' '{print $1}')

echo $row

echo "<FORM>
    <SELECT onChange=
      "document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
      <OPTION VALUE="#" SELECTED>     DAY     </OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="111.html"> $array </SELECT>
  </FORM> "



echo "

</PRE>

</body>
</html>
"
```

But the result is :

[image]

And I need... This :

[image]

I think I must use a for loop but I don't know how. Can you show me ?

Comment: Please add screenshots instead of photos of your screen. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
array=$(cat CLUSTER_1.txt | awk -F',' '{print $1}')
echo "<FORM><SELECT onChange='document.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value'>"
echo "<OPTION VALUE='#' SELECTED>     DAY     </OPTION>"
echo "$array" | while read WHILEDATE; do
      echo "<OPTION VALUE='111.html'>" $WHILEDATE "</SELECT>"
done
echo "</FORM>"
```

Comment: Hello ! Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work ! :/